# Calling predicates from another predicate

Tags: list, function, prolog

```
   list([1,2,3,4]).

len([],0).
len([_|T],X):-
    len(T,X1),
    X is X1+1.

sum([],0).
sum([H|T],X):-
    sum(T,X1),
    X is X1+H.

max_element([X],X).
max_element([H1,H2|T],Max):-
    H1>H2,!,
    max_element([H1|T],Max).
max_element([H1,H2|T],Max):-
    max_element([H2,T],Max).

min_element([X],X).
min_element([H1,H2|T],Min):-
    H1<H2,!,
    min_element([H1|T],Min).
min_element([H1,H2|T],Min):-
    min_element([H2,T],Min).
```

Hello, I'm completely new to Prolog and I'm supposed to make a predicate `start/1` which loads a list of integers and calls predicates listed above, it's also supposed to return values separated with new line characters. I'm terribly sorry if that doesnt make sense but I have no idea how to implement this, would be greatful for any help for a begginer, much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-edited some of the functions you've written. So that I would be easy to print them the way you wanted.

```
sum([X],X):- write(X).
sum([H,H1|T],Z):- H2 is H+H1 , sum([H2|T],Z).

min([],Z):- write(Z).
min([H|T],Z):- H<Z , Z1 is H , min(T, Z1).
min([H|T],Z):- H>Z ,min(T ,Z).

max([],Z):- write(Z).
max([H|T],Z):- H>Z , Z1 is H , max(T, Z1).
max([H|T],Z):- H<Z ,max(T ,Z).

len([],S):- write(S).
len([_|T],Z):-  Z1 is Z+1 , len(T,Z1) .


list(Z):- write('sum :- ') , sum(Z,_), nl ,write('min:- ') ,  min(Z,99) , nl, write('max:- '), max(Z,0) ,nl, write('len:- ') , len(Z,0).
```

The query you have to pass is below to get output the way wanted. Hope this helped you.

```
?- list([1,2,3]).
sum :- 6
min:- 1
max:- 3
len:- 3
true
```